# Group extension

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-extensions

I am getting blurred about group extensions. Let $A,B,C$ be groups.

1. If $G=(A{:}B).C$ and $A$ is characteristic in $G$, then $G=A.(B.C)$. But is it also true that $G=A{:}(B.C)$ ?
2. If $G=A.(B{:}C)$, then $G=(A.B).C$. But is it true that $G=(A.B){:}C$ ?

Note that $G=A.B$ means $G/A\cong B$; and $G=A{:}B$ means semidirect product of $A$ and $B$ with $A\lhd G$.

Comment: What is $\,(A:B)\,$ , anyway? I'm guessing that period is product (of subgroups)...?

Comment: @DonAntonio: $A:B$ is the semidirect product of $A$ and $B$. Putting a bracket around means it is a group.

Comment: Oh, I see! The external semidirect product $\,A\rtimes B\,$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to (1), no. Take $G$ to be the direct product of a cyclic group of order $9$ by a group of order $2$. Let $A$ be the unique subgroup of order $3$, and $B$ the unique subgroup of order $2$, so $C$ is cyclic of order $3$. Then $AB$ is the unique subgroup of order $6$, so $A$ cannot have a complement $B.C$ of order $6$.

The very same example show that the answer to (2) is also negative, as there's no subgroup $C$ of order $3$ besides $A$.

Comment: Nice to see you answer my question again! Just reckon it is so easy by taking counterexamples. Thanks very much!

Comment: @user60079, you're welcome. It is useful to build up a small stock of groups to be used as (counter)examples.